# Outlook 2010 overriding font-family from Arial to Times New Roman

Tags: outlook, html-email

I'm programmatically sending HTML-formatted email, and setting the font as Arial throughout (`font-family: Arial;`).  When the messages arrive in Outlook 2010, text in `table` elements is in Times New Roman.  Text in `div` elements is fine in Arial.  If I `View Source`, copy into an HTML file, and view in a browser, all fonts function as expected (it's all Arial).

Some Google [results](http://www.outlookforums.com/threads/40200-showing-times-new-roman-while-i-set-arial-html-messages/) show that Outlook will fall back to its default font (Times New Roman) when none is specified, but that's not what's happening here.

Why is Outlook forcing my email to display in Times New Roman when specified otherwise?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Even if you set `font-family: arial` to table, it still wont work. You need to specifically set the font for each `td` inside your `table` to get it right.

Comment: I really hoped this wasn't the right answer but it did the trick, cheers!

Comment: This is correct, Outlook doesn't seem to pick up the parent element's styling. You have to style the current container or the text reverts to defaults.

Comment: I assume `td{font-family:arial}` isn't what you mean?

Comment: @ThomasAhle: yes you are right. You have to give inline styles and not styles in style block or external file.

Comment: Solution by @Userpassword works well for Outlook if that is the only target.

Answer (score 29):

```
<!--[if mso]>
<style> body,table tr,table td,a, span,table.MsoNormalTable {  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;  }</style>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Working in Outlook 2016 as well.

Comment: Just tested on outlook 2007, 2010, 2016, 2019. This 1 liner works well

Answer (score 10):

The `table` in question was nested in a `div` that had `font-family:Arial;` in its style, but the `table` did not have a font set.  So tables don't inherit fonts (and perhaps other things) from their containers in HTML emails in some clients.

Comment: It's enough to set font for table. Every div is ont needed. Tested on Outlook 2010

Answer (score 6):

This issue was happening from outlook 2007 and the previous solutions didn't work for me, the only solution that seems to work is wrapping the text with `<font face="arial, sans-serif">My text with arial</font>`

Comment: Thank you! I had a table with the font specified for every td and it was turning the first row into Times New Roman. The font tag around the offending text fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with Outlook 2007, you must define font-family on table . Otherwise it will set to default serif font.

Answer (score 1):

The <font> tag is deprecated but since Outlook 2010 is removing (almost all) styles, this is the only way it works.

Answer (score 1):

`table.MsoNormalTable
    {font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman";}`
Open your HTML with Text Pad, and change it to Arial.

Answer (score 1):

None of above methods worked for me, using a custom font linked with @font-face. had to work with conditional tags for Outlook. Took me quite some time to figure out how exactly. So I've set up a code example: I was still having some troubles implementing this in my situation so I've shared a code example for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21626196/135654

Answer (score 1):

You can put your style to "span" tag, It will works good.

```
   <td>
       <span style="font-family: "Times New Roman"></span>
   </td>
```