# An image for outlook and another image for others

Tags: html, email, outlook

I have this code for html email (for example)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<span>Email content</span>

<!--[if mso]>
 <img src="НТТР://site.com/image_for_outlook.jpg">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !mso]><!-->
 <img src="НТТР://site.com/image_not_for_outlook.gif">
<!--<![endif]-->

<span>Email content</span>
</body>
</html>
```

How to hide gif animation in Outlook?
There is many information for this but it's not work between "body" tags.

Comment: Do you want to hide it in the desktop client version of Outlook only, or also in the webmail version?

Comment: Have you seen this post?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254711/html-emails-fallback-for-mso-conditional

Comment: Only for Outlook in MS Office.

Comment: Omnivore, it's not work.
Code http://jsfiddle.net/fHRU2/
Result http://i.imgur.com/xQXnKgM.jpg