# Email Fallback Outlook Gmail

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, gmail

Hello you wonderful smart friends.

I'm trying to set a fallback system for email clients. After read this [HTML Emails: fallback for mso conditional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254711/html-emails-fallback-for-mso-conditional) and other great blogs I seem to be missing something still. I'm able to get the the email to display the correctly in Outlook but in Gmail the VML is still rendered which gives me two images.

```
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td rowspan=2 class="desktop">

                <!--[if mso]>
                    <v:rect style="width:600px;height:281px;" strokecolor="none">
                        <v:fill type="tile" color="#363636" src="http://www.frugi.org/emailpi/assets/header.jpg" /></v:fill>
                    </v:rect>
                    <v:shape id="someName" style="position:absolute;width:600px;height:281px;">
                        <p style="font-family:Georgia; font-size:13px;"><h2 style="color:Red;">Text Over Image Hack!!!</h2></p>
                    </v:shape>
                    <div style="width:0px; height:0px; overflow:hidden; display:none; visibility:hidden; mso-hide:all;">
                <![endif]-->
                    <img src="_PT_icon_personalize_05.png"  style="width:0; overflow:hidden; display:none; float:left" >
                <!--[if mso]>
                    </div>
                <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!--[if mso]>
                <div style="width:0px; height:0px; overflow:hidden; display:none; visibility:hidden; mso-hide:all;">
        <![endif]-->
        <td colspan=2 ><h2 style="color:Red;max-width:480px; width:0; overflow:hidden; display:none;">Text Over Image Hack!!!</h2></td>
        <!--[if mso]>
            </div>
        <![endif]-->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Am I missing something here?

Outlook

[image]

Gmail

[image]

Comment: Not sure is this the issue, but you are wrapping div around td

Comment: Take a look at [backgrounds.cm](http://backgrounds.cm) for a solid VML example that works across both (all major) clients.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you John!!!

```
<!-- BANNER -->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="281" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td background="http://www.frugi.org/emailpi/assets/header.jpg" bgcolor="#7bceeb" valign="top">
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:598;height:281px;">
        <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.frugi.org/emailpi/assets/header.jpg" color="#7bceeb" />
        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
        <![endif]-->
                            <div>

                            </div>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        </v:textbox>
        </v:rect>
        <![endif]-->
    </td>
</tr>
```