# HTML email: text looks weird when using VML in Gmail

Tags: html, email, outlook, gmail, vml

I followed https://backgrounds.cm/ and use VML to generate a text-over-image. It looks fine in Outlook, however I realised that the text becomes weird when viewed in Gmail. Basically, the weird text can be seen at [Email Fallback Outlook Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221388/email-fallback-outlook-gmail) under the Gmail section.

You can see that there is a weird border around the text. Is there a way to resolve this? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.