# why gmail is rendering outlook html

Tags: html, email, html-email

```html
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">

<body>
    <table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="5">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1">qnty</td>
                <td colspan="2">price</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1">100</td>
                <td colspan="1">
                    <!--[if mso]>
                        <span style="position: relative;color: black;">
                            $7.75
                            <v:rect stroke="f" fill="t" fillcolor="red" style="width: 40px; height: 1px; position: absolute; left: 0px;top: 8px"></v:rect>
                        </span>
                    <![endif]-->
                    <!--[if !mso]>
                        <span style="position: relative;color: black;">
                            $1232
                            <v:rect stroke="f" fill="t" fillcolor="red" style="width: 40px; height: 1px; position: absolute; left: 0px;top: 8px"></v:rect>
                        </span>
                    <![endif]-->

                </td>
                <td colspan="1">0.25</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

I Am using the above HTML to show price 7.75 in outlook and 1232 in other emails like GMAL. The code works fine for outlook but it shows the same result for Gmail.

Gmail
[image: Gmail updated screen shot]

Outlook
[image: outlook screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML Emails: fallback for mso conditional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254711/html-emails-fallback-for-mso-conditional)

Comment: from you screens shot it seems you are looking at both the emails in Outlook? For the codes to work, you will need to check in Outlook (desktop) and Gmail (web browser).

Comment: @Syfer i have updated the image. It was uploaded wrong by me.

Comment: @KenY-N not exactly as gmail is showing same price as that of outlook can check updated image

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `!mso` conditional comment is incorrect. The correct formatting to hide content from Outlook and have it visible elsewhere is:

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<span style="position: relative;color: black;">
    $1232
    <v:rect stroke="f" fill="t" fillcolor="red" style="width: 40px; height: 1px; position: absolute; left: 0px;top: 8px"></v:rect>
</span>
<!--<![endif]-->
```