# the Outlook destop client when forwarding an email converts buttons to images

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am sending an email with code from https://buttons.cm/
And the buttons looks great, but when they are forwarded the buttons in outlook desktop client removes the link and then converts the button to images.

Also the origanl email invite if is forwarded using gmail/outlook mobile client converts button to less attractive state but is still usable.

First of all why does outlook does this? Secondly is there any way we can avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

> First of all why does outlook does this?

Outlook for desktop uses Word as email editor. It applies its own rules to the HTML content. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.

> Secondly is there any way we can avoid this?

Try to use the supported by Word HTML elements, attributes and cascading style sheets properties.

You see an image when the `<!--[if mso]>` condition fails to detect Office applications. Read more about these attributes in the [Outlook conditional CSS](https://stackoverflow.design/email/base/mso/) article. Also you may find the [HTML Emails: fallback for mso conditional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254711/html-emails-fallback-for-mso-conditional) page helpful.